# How do I keep edges away from forest nodes?

Tags: forest, edge

```
\documentclass[convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand{\difference}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
  \hline
  0&1&0&1&\ldots\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\differenceshort}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
  \hline
  0&1&\ldots\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    inner sep=1pt
  }
  [\ldots,rotate=90,parent anchor=west,calign=child edge
  [\difference,node options={label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 3},
    label=left:{\scriptsize Layer 3}}
  [\differenceshort,node options={label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 1},
    label=left:{\scriptsize Layer 2}}
  [\differenceshort] [\differenceshort] [\ldots,base=top]]
  [\differenceshort,label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 2}
  [\differenceshort] [\differenceshort] [\ldots,label=right:{\scriptsize Inputs}]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The edges between the last terminal nodes and their parents cross their left siblings. How can I have the edges programmatically move away from other nodes?

Comment: You can't. This is explained in the documentation. Forest tries hard to avoid clashes, but there are corner cases where that won't work and you'll need to intervene manually to adjust things. Whether this is one of those known cases or not, I'm not sure.

Comment: However, in this case, using Forest's `align` might work better than using tabulars independently.

Comment: Removing `inner sep=1pt` avoids the clashes.

Comment: @cfr To fix the issue, I could either remove `innerp sep=1pt` or add `align=center` to nodes with `\ldots` as the content.

Comment: @cfr Just for some formal closure, I want to close this question by choosing an answer. Can you post an answer?

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to manually add `tabular` environments rather than using Forest's. It definitely copes better when it knows what is going on.

Comment: @cfr I agree. I used tabular becuase I was just getting used to forest.

Comment: Square edges can also be quite helpful in these kinds of cases - or `forked edges` as Forest calls them ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no programmatic way to 100% ensure no clashes. See the documentation for details of why. Basically, it would be far too expensive. However, in cases like this, things can be greatly improved.

Using Forest's `align` option rather than independently specified `tabular`s avoids edges clashing with nodes in this case because this aligns the top of the `tabular`s with the `baseline` by default (explanation from [Sašo's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307559/how-do-i-keep-edges-away-from-forest-nodes/307564?noredirect=1#comment746587_307564)):

[image: no clashes]

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  diff/.style={%
    align=c|c|c|c|c,
    delay={%
      content={%
        \hline
        0&1&0&1&\ldots\\
        \hline
      }
    }
  },
  diff short/.style={%
    align=c|c|c,
    delay={%
      content={%
        \hline
        0&1&\ldots\\
        \hline
      }
    }
  },
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    inner sep=1pt
  }
  [\ldots, rotate=90, parent anchor=west, calign=child edge
    [, diff, node options={label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 3}, label=left:{\scriptsize Layer 3}}
      [, diff short, node options={label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 1}, label=left:{\scriptsize Layer 2}}
        [, diff short]
        [, diff short]
        [\ldots]
      ]
      [, diff short, label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 2}
        [, diff short]
        [, diff short]
        [\ldots, label=right:{\scriptsize Inputs}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Adding

```
for siblings={%
  anchor=center
},
```

to the definition of `diff short` and aligning parental edges with those of their middle child when they have an odd number of children gets us

[image: centring dots a bit]

But perhaps the best option is to add

```
base=b
```

for the tree and

```
for siblings={%
  minimum size=1em,
},
```

to the definitions of `diff` and `diff short` to ensure a bit more space around things like `\ldots`. This produces

[image: bottom alignment with minimum sizing for siblings]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  diff/.style={%
    align=c|c|c|c|c,
    for siblings={%
      minimum size=1em,
    },
    delay={%
      content={%
        \hline
        0&1&0&1&\ldots\\
        \hline
      }
    }
  },
  diff short/.style={%
    align=c|c|c,
    for siblings={%
      minimum size=1em,
    },
    delay={%
      content={%
        \hline
        0&1&\ldots\\
        \hline
      }
    }
  },
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    base=b,
    inner sep=1pt,
    if={isodd(n_children())}{%
      tempcounta/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1}{int((n_children()+1)/2)},
      for n/.wrap pgfmath arg={{#1}{%
          calign with current edge
        }}{int((n_children()+1)/2)}
    }{}
  },
  [\ldots, rotate=90, parent anchor=west, calign=child edge
    [, diff, node options={label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 3}, label=left:{\scriptsize Layer 3}}
      [, diff short, node options={label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 1}, label=left:{\scriptsize Layer 2}}
        [, diff short]
        [, diff short]
        [\ldots]
      ]
      [, diff short, label=right:{\scriptsize Difference 2}
        [, diff short]
        [, diff short]
        [\ldots, label=right:{\scriptsize Inputs}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you indent forest tree syntax? emacs `auctex` mode doesn't do it for me.

Comment: @crocket It drives me crazy - Kile doesn't either. I do it by hand. Well, I can highlight stuff and tell it to indent it, of course, but I can't just tell it to sort it all out. I just can't stand working with code I can't *see* the structure of as I end up spending more time trying to find errors and it is just more efficient to take the time to do it properly. When I'm actually creating a tree, it is only slightly annoying as I just do it automatically mostly. But it is a pain taking somebody else's code!

Comment: `align` works better than manual `tabular` environment only because forest's default is `\begin{tabular}[t]{...}`. :-)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović See edit. How is the documentation going?

Comment: I'm still on forest `2015/07/15 v1.0.10`. Why does `base=bottom` make a different result from `base=b`?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović ^^ Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @crocket As far as I knew, those should be equivalent because `base=bottom` is just syntactic sugar for readability - you still only get `base=b` because `b` and `t` are the two choices Forest recognises as making sense.